# How to setup GDB when compiling using makefile?

Tags: c, macos, makefile, gdb

I am trying to compile my project for debugging using a Makefile. The makefile currently generates multiple different object file and then compiles a single executable from all of these different object file. The make file is as follows:

```
CC=gcc

Scheduler: scheduler-exec.o scheduler-impl.o lab5_linkedlist.o lab5_queue.o
        $(CC) -o Scheduler scheduler-impl.o scheduler-exec.o lab5_linkedlist.o lab5_queue.o

scheduler-exec.o: scheduler-exec.c
        $(CC) -c -o scheduler-exec.o scheduler-exec.c

scheduler-impl.o: scheduler-impl.c
        $(CC) -c -o scheduler-impl.o scheduler-impl.c

queue.o: lab5_queue.c
        $(CC) -c -o lab5_queue.o lab5_queue.c

linkedlist.o: lab5_linkedlist.c
        $(CC) -c -o lab5_linkedlist.o lab5_linkedlist.c

clean:
        rm *.o
```

I would like to maintain this distributed compiling system such that I am generating these different object files and then compiling them together using the `Scheduler` task in the Makefile. I tried adding the `-g` flag to all the tasks but when i ran `gdb` on the `Scheduler` executable that was generated, it still didn't have the debugging information. The output of the `gdb` program is this:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from Scheduler...
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
```

and the program is just stuck there. I would appreciate a method where I can compile this program using the Makefile and be able to get the variable information. Thanks

I tried the following makefile it didnt work:

```
CC=gcc

Scheduler: scheduler-exec.o scheduler-impl.o lab5_linkedlist.o lab5_queue.o
        $(CC) -o Scheduler scheduler-impl.o scheduler-exec.o lab5_linkedlist.o lab5_queue.o -g

scheduler-exec.o: scheduler-exec.c
        $(CC) -c -o scheduler-exec.o scheduler-exec.c -g

scheduler-impl.o: scheduler-impl.c
        $(CC) -c -o scheduler-impl.o scheduler-impl.c -g

queue.o: lab5_queue.c
        $(CC) -c -o lab5_queue.o lab5_queue.c -g

linkedlist.o: lab5_linkedlist.c
        $(CC) -c -o lab5_linkedlist.o lab5_linkedlist.c -g

clean:
        rm *.o
```

Comment: Did you add `-g` to the executable rule as well?

Comment: Do you mean that when building without Makefile, GDB does not get stuck?

Comment: I tried adding -g to all the tasks. Editted question to reflect this

Comment: Could be macOS related issue. Have you tried the same on some Linux?

Comment: Yes I have. Same result.

Comment: What does the output of `readelf --wide --section-headers ...` look like?  Run it on `Scheduler` and, e.g., `scheduler-exec.o` -- you should see section names beginning with `.debug` (or similar).

Comment: @G.M. Hey so i booted onto an Xubuntu image, the debugger loaded the symbols properly. But when I try to use the same makefile on a mac it doesnt work. running readelf on Xubuntu did show the debug flags. Is there a readelf equivalent that I can use to check my mac build?

Comment: On macos try using `objdump` rather than `readelf` (same option flags).  Can you also edit your question to show the output of `gcc --version`?

Comment: Ok so I ran objdump but it didn't output anything for debugging. But then I recreated my gdb certificate and the symbols are now loaded into the GDB but it sill doesn't run my program. But since the symbols are loading it is no longer a problem for this thread. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Did you `--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove most of your rules, and instead use the built-in rules:

```make
CC := gcc
CFLAGS += -g
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds

Scheduler: scheduler-exec.o scheduler-impl.o lab5_linkedlist.o lab5_queue.o
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
        rm *.o
```

That's all you need.  Now rebuild everything (`make -B`).  You can check that you have debugging information:

```sh
$ file Scheduler
```

Output will be something like

> Scheduler: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=5812e87410be09796cfed309a265dbcff1cf5d5e, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, **with debug_info, not stripped**